# Battery behaving erratically

Tags: power-management, indicator, battery

I have got Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP Pavilion g4 2049tx laptop. The battery indicator is behaving erratically. It goes to critical mode (<10%) immediately after reaching 57%. It charges up pretty quickly (~20 minutes) but discharges quickly as well. The machine (and the battery) are ~3 years old, so it may be a hardware issue. However, I want to rule out any OS related issues before changing the battery.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that one or more of the cells in the battery are failing and hence the total capacity is severely reduced.  The battery uevent sys interface should be able to show the design full capacity and you current maximum battery capacity.  For example, I have an old Dell laptop that shows:

```
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent 
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Unknown
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=11100000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=12399000
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN=4800000
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL=2476000
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW=2418000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=97
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Normal
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=DELL 00
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=53355
```

In the above example, the CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN is much higher than the actually CHARGE_FULL, showing that the battery has some cell degradation since it cannot be charged to the design full level.

Lithium-Ion laptop batteries can handle about 1000 charge/discharge cycles, so 3 years of usage is probably hitting this threshold.

Comment: I see. However, the output on my machine  (charging at 84%) is:
   POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
    POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Charging
    POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
    POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
    POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
    POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=10800000
    POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=12563000
    POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=715000
    POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN=3200000
    POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL=3200000
    POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW=2688000
    POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=84
    POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=Primary
    POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=Hewlett-Packard
    POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=

Comment: This means that the cells are all working fine, right?

Comment: From what I can make out, they look in rather good shape.

Comment: In most hardware that I've worked on, the SMART battery controls are handled by an embedded controller and I have seen these sometimes get into a confused state and give sporadic or bad readings.  Removing the battery and AC power to the machine for a few minutes may be enough to ensure the embedded controller is power cycled and there is a slim chance this may fix things.  Always worth a try.

Comment: Update: The solution suggested by @colin didn't ameliorate the problem completely, but it did seem to have some beneficial effect. The battery is still not performing at the expected level, but the drastic change after ~57% seems to have abated for the time being.